# Error while creating a jar through artifacts in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

First of all, i searched for similar questions and i found something, but nothing helps me out.

I'm trying to create a jar file in intellij using the artifact, but everytime i build i have the error: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.wms.test`

This is my test.java file

```
package com.test.wms;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // empty
    }
}
```

Then i went into `Project Structure` -> `Artifacts` and added a new artifact, selected the type (`jar`), selected the name (`test.jar`) and generated the `manifest.mf` (autogenerated from the artifact page on intelij)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.test.wms.test
```

And this is the artifact edit page
Then i build the project and try to lunch in konsole with `java -jar test.jar` and the error is always the same: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.wms.test`

This is my project structure:

[image: jarstructure]

And this is my artifact edit page

[image]

Where is the mistake?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by myself, when i was creating the jar from the artifact i was selecting `empty` instead of `From modules with dependancy` (the output is the same but with this option works, maybe the IDE does something particular)